# Data where cells have factors separated by comma

Tags: python, r, dataframe, powerbi, data-manipulation

There is data-frame with cells that have factors ('At a pub', 'At home' ...) that are separated by a comma and are not the same for each cell. See the picture bellow (how excel sees the CSV file):
[image]

How can I separate each factor into a column so that the same factors would be in the same column and blanks for others - create dummy columns? I have many of these columns for different types of drinks (vodka, gin and others)

There are possible tools such as R, Python and Power BI at my disposal.

Tried simple MS Excel and some of its commands and capabilities.

Comment: Please specify a language - SO isn't an ideation service for possible solutions. We can help you with a specific problem, but we can't design a solution for you.

Comment: Looks like a csv file but your Excel is not configured for comma-separation. Don't you get the table you want with `read.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in base R (plus `reshape2`) or in `data.table` as well, but here's a working premise for flow to get what you think you need.

```r
DF <- data.frame(id=1:2, text=c("Pubs in the old town,At a club", "House party,Pubs in the old town"))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest, pivot_wider
DF %>%
  mutate(text = strsplit(text, ","), fake = 1) %>%
  unnest(text) %>%
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = "text", values_from = "fake") %>%
  mutate(across(-id, Negate(is.na)))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#      id `Pubs in the old town` `At a club` `House party`
#   <int> <lgl>                  <lgl>       <lgl>        
# 1     1 TRUE                   TRUE        FALSE        
# 2     2 TRUE                   FALSE       TRUE
```

This won't deal correctly with similar phrases that are off by spelling or spacing; for that, you may need to go into NLP or similar to reduce a phrase to comparable states. There is room for more conditioning of the data here (e.g., `trimws`, reducing repeated inner-spaces, case differences) that might mitigate some of those concerns; for this, you may want to do the conditioning in the long form before `pivot_wider(.)`, since you'll have one column's values to fix, not column names.